# Change a textbox text from inside Class

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have some objects in my `Main form` like textboxes and panels.
So I want to change a textbox text or size or visibility from my class.
I made my `textBox1` from `Main form` public.
So I created a class named `Class1`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void test()
    {
        Main form = new Main();
        form.textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And in my `Main form` I run the code from my class:

```
private void MainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1.test();
}
```

But nothing has changed in my textbox. Is the way I bring my textbox inside my class wrong ?

Comment: Well you creates a **new** `Form`...

Comment: Other than possibly "object reference not set to an instance of an object", this might be the most asked question on SO. The key is realizing Forms are just classes. [Check this oldie but goodie](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you construct a **new** `Form` here:

```
public static void test() {
    Main form = new Main(); // constructing a new form?
    form.textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

You can however solve this problem by **passing a reference to the `Form`**:

```
public static void test(Main form) {
    form.textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

and call with:

```
private void MainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Class1.test(this); // pass a reference to the Main form
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was what i was looking for.So my problem was when i construck a 'new' Form doesnt include the elements inside them?

Comment: The elements are in that form, but these are new elements. So altering a textbox in the "new" form has no impact on the old form that is displayed.

Comment: Ok nice explanation! THANK YOU!

Comment: Plain `<code>` tag works and then I can use `<b>`. **this** changed my life!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Yeah, that was a great discovery :)

Answer (score 1):

in your `test` method, you're making *new* instance of your form (which is not the one you called that method from)... new and still hidden form.

To change existing `Textbox`, you have to pass reference to `Form` or `TextBox`. So, change yout `test` method with `TextBox` parameter, something like this:

```
public static void test(TextBox tb)
{
    tb.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

use it like this:

```
private void MainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1.test(this.textBox1);
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. But as i wrote i dont want to declare only one textbox in my class. I want much textboxes and panels.So i thing Willem Van Onsem has answer my question thank you at all.